# Debugging Error #1010 Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

The following piece of the as3 code is written for a card game, and I am curious, why I get Error #1010?

```
var backHands:Array = new Array();
var numberOfPlayingCards = 0;
function initBackHands(){ 
    var i:int;
    var j:int;

    for(j=1;j<4;j++){
        var newBacks:Array = new Array();
        for(i=0;i<13;i++){
            newBacks[i] = new CBack();
            addChild(newBacks[i]);
        }
        backHands[j-1] = newBacks;
    }
}
function removeBack(p:int){
try{
    if(position[p]>0){
        var index:int = (numberOfPlayingCards/4);
        index = 12- index;
        if(contains(backHands[position[p] - 1][index])){
            removeChild(backHands[position[p] - 1][index]);
        }
    }

    }catch(error:Error){
    trace("playCard= NOPC: "+ numberOfPlayingCards +
            " index: " + index +
            " position: " + (position[p] - 1) + 
            " err: "+ error);
    }
    numberOfPlayingCards ++;

}
```

and this is the error log:

```
playCard= NOPC: 0 index: 12 position: 1 err: TypeError: Error #1010 
playCard= NOPC: 1 index: 12 position: 0 err: TypeError: Error #1010 
playCard= NOPC: 1 index: 12 position: 2 err: TypeError: Error #1010 
playCard= NOPC: 2 index: 12 position: 0 err: TypeError: Error #1010 
playCard= NOPC: 2 index: 12 position: 1 err: TypeError: Error #1010 
playCard= NOPC: 3 index: 12 position: 2 err: TypeError: Error #1010 
playCard= NOPC: 4 index: 11 position: 2 err: TypeError: Error #1010 
playCard= NOPC: 5 index: 11 position: 1 err: TypeError: Error #1010
playCard= NOPC: 6 index: 11 position: 0 err: TypeError: Error #1010 
playCard= NOPC: 8 index: 10 position: 0 err: TypeError: Error #1010 
playCard= NOPC: 10 index: 10 position: 2 err: TypeError: Error #1010
playCard= NOPC: 11 index: 10 position: 1 err: TypeError: Error #1010
playCard= NOPC: 12 index: 9 position: 0 err: TypeError: Error #1010
```

The question is which line makes the error and why the NOPC does not increase regularly while we call removeBack function for each turn.

Please note that p is an integer between 0 and 3, and position is an array of integer of size 4 containing the position of each player(0,1, 2 or 3)

Comment: it is obvious it cant get any array or object value for backHands[position[p] - 1] and you cant get the [index]

Comment: @Bolzano, thanks for your answer, but why is that? As you can see in initBackHands() function , I initialise the bakcHands array

Answer (score 0):

you are filling backHands Array with using

```
for(j=1;j<4;j++){
 backHands[j-1] = newBacks;
```

so if you call removeBack(3); it is trying to find backHands[position[3] - 1] and you said that position array is something like this

```
var position:Array = [1,2,3,4]
```

so it turns to backHands[4-1] -> backHands[3]  and it is undefined as you can see your for loop is increasing j to 3

```
backHands[1-1] = newBacks;//j=1
backHands[2-1] = newBacks;//j=2
backHands[3-1] = newBacks;//j=3
```

as you can see there is no 4 for j because you typed as j < 4 not j <=4

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I really appreciate that, but sorry for my bad, the position array contains (0, 1, 2 or 3). Sorry again for the inconvenience and I've already edited the question.

Comment: can you add your removeBack calls too ?

Comment: when the player p(0, 1, 2,  or 3) plays a card, the server calls this function. The thing that I do not understand is, even if something happens in try and catch, why in error log the NOPC does not increase at each call?

Comment: ok when you call like removeBack(0);removeBack(1);
 removeBack(2);
 removeBack(3); it works for me but server callbacks are asynchronus so NOPC is not increasing somehow because of try catch i need to check try catch flow if you have any other thing to say about your flow please write it is interesting realy